# Struts2 - How to split struts.xml file

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, struts2

I've got a huge struts.xml file and I want to add some logic in my struts file. I've decided to split it on many files like :

struts-users.xml
struts-tvshows.xml

My struts.xml file is at it follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true"></constant>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"></constant>
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="package"></constant>

    <include file="struts-user.xml" />
    <include file="struts-tvshows.xml" />
</struts>
```

I'm running into this error : Exception starting struts2 filter

The exception stacktrace says : Caused by: The package name 'frontoffice' at location ... (location of my struts-tvshows.xml location).

So my error comes from the fact that I define the package named "frontoffice" in both files. I have to keep all my actions in the same package...

Does someone has a clue ?

Comment: Can you please post exception stacktrace?

Comment: The exception stacktrace says : "The package name 'frontoffice' is already been used by another package" ...

Comment: I had maintained separate configuration files but in my case i defined my module name and never duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot define a package across multiple config files. I don't understand why you need to keep them in the same package, though--package names are completely arbitrary.

If your concern is an existing package definition, simply have the new packages extend that package.

From the names of the include files it looks like there's zero reason to keep them in the same package since they *appear* to have completely unrelated functionality.